# Model directly outputting code

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whenever I attempt to load a model in CodeIgniter it outputs the content of that model file to the web browser. Here are some examples of my current setup.

**Filename: test.php**

```
class test extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_test_data() {
        return 'test data';
    }
}
```

**Filename: home.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('nav');
        $this->load->view('dyn_content');

        $this->load->model('Test');
        $data['query'] = $this->Blog->get_test_data();

        $this->load->view('footer');

    }
}
```

**Logs from loading the page**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> File loaded: application/views/header.php
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> File loaded: application/views/nav.php
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> File loaded: application/views/dyn_content.php
DEBUG - 2011-12-27 15:43:56 --> Model Class Initialized
```

As you can see it stops after loading the model. When I comment out the lines that load the model (or even just the one that assigns the results to $data['query']) the page loads perfectly and does exactly what I would expect.

Can anyone see anything that is missing or setup incorrectly?

Comment: What about first letter case?

Comment: +1 @zerkms - also you say `it outputs the content of that model file to the web browser` - have you by any chance forgotten to put an opening `<?php` tag in `test.php`? Or used the short `<?` tag on a server where `short_open_tag` is disabled?

Comment: Of course, thank you @DaveRandom. That was the problem. It is working now.

Comment: @DaveRandom it will not allow me to until the question has been up for 8 hours or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice provided in the comments by @DaveRandom, I had simply left off the `<?php` tags. I guess I was still thinking about views.

Thanks @DaveRandom.